# jQuery UI Dialog will not close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

On my web page I have a button that opens a modal jQuery dialog.  The code that runs when the button is clicked is as follows:

```
$('#main-onoffline-container').append('<div id="dialog-modal-a"></div>');

    $("#dialog-modal-a").dialog({
        title:'Add Tags'
        , autoOpen: false
        , modal: true
        , height: 540
        , width:700
        , close: function (ev, ui) { alert('closing'); }
        ,open: function() {
            $("#dialog-modal-a").html('Some html will go here')
        }
    });

    $("#dialog-modal-a").dialog("open");
```

As you can see, I am adding a div to the DOM, then calling the dialog method against the newly added div.

The dialog opens fine and displays the html plus the X close button.  However, when I hit the X button to close the dialog it does not close.  The console shows the following error from jquery-1.6.4.min.js:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

**UPDATE:**
After a lengthy session I have detected that the order of certain js libraries are influencing this:

If I include files as follows then the problem appears:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If I included files as follows then the problem disappears:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This seems really strange - I thought that you should include the core jQuery stuff right at the top of the file?

(The validate lib is Jörn Zaefferer plugin)

I have raised a different question to take this forward: [jQuery library include order causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614142/jquery-library-include-order-causes-error)

Comment: Is this the only code you have on that page? It may be unrelated to this, looks like the browser is running out of memory somehow.

Comment: I have loads of other code running on the page, with lots of Javascript objects being created and manipulated.  However, until this moment nothing has caused any console errors to appear.

Comment: If you take this code out is everything still ok ? The reason i say this is because the current code works fine in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BHaEj/13/

Comment: Well, bit tricky to dismantle the functionality.  I'll see if I can create a jsfiddle extract...

Comment: What is the code that opens the dialog?

Comment: @Terry `$("#dialog-modal-a").dialog("open");`

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder sorry I knew that, I meant what is triggering that in the OP's application.

Comment: The following html triggers the dialog creation:
<a href="javascript:molecule_tagEditor();" class="ipadbutton" >

Comment: The problem was due to a conflict between libraries.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614142/jquery-library-include-order-causes-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to a js library conflict - please see my final comments in the main question

Comment: I had the same problem with twitter bootstrap 2.3 which conflict with jquery-ui. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6887

Answer (score 0):

Try to pull out of the function $.dialog the closing event handling:

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried that and the event handler does not get called - the error triggers before the handler gets called

Comment: The only thing I can advise: put a breakpoint at the location where an error occurs, and examine the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're appending the dialog to the page and opening it right away.  I assume you've left out code.  Generally with this plugin want you want to do is:

Create the dialog container in the HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-modal-a"></div>
```

Initialize it on $().ready() (which hides it by default when `autoOpen: false`) then open it on an event or page load:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-modal-a").dialog({
        title:'Add Tags',
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 540,
        width:700,
        close: function (ev, ui) { alert('closing'); }
    });

    $('#somethinkToClick').click(function() {
        $('#dialog-modal-a').html('some html');
        $("#dialog-modal-a").dialog("open");
    });

    /* OR
    $('#somethinkToClick').click(function() {
        $('#dialog-modal-a').html('some html');
        $("#dialog-modal-a").dialog("open");
    });
    */
}
```

Comment: You don't have to create the dialog before, there's nothing wrong with injecting a div in the DOM then using it for the dialog, works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/BHaEj/13/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, .dialog('destroy') did the trick for me.   There may still be a js version mismatch.