# How to fix Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded jsplumb Error on Javascript application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

currently I'm trying to implement a javascript application which uses jsplumb plugin too. In the bottom of page, I gave the versions of `jquery-ui` and `jquery.js`. In some part of it, I've following function :

```
jsPlumb.bind("dblclick", function(c) {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      width:400,
      height:250,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Remove Connection": function() {
          jsPlumb.detach(c);
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
});
```

And  this is my corresponding part in html:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete connections." style="display:none;">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This connection will be removed.<br/>Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

When I double click on the screen I got the following error  and the dialog box is not closed.

error: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

So, in order to find which part of it causes this error, I replaced the above code with the following version :

```
jsPlumb.bind("dblclick", function(c) {
   jsPlumb.detach(c);
 }
```

and Error is gone. But, I don't know how to fix my problem with the original version. What should I do for this?

**Edit**
After I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614142/jquery-library-include-order-causes-error) answer, I think I might have version conflict.Unfortunatelly, I do not know how to detect it. Is there anyone who could help me about that issue too?

**Last edit**
When I click the console on chrome, I've found version information of packages. These are:

```
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.2 
jquery-ui 1.9.2-min.js
```